# How to enable thrift in Cassandra in Cloudera?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, thrift, cloudera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6pgL.jpg)I'm new to Cassandra and cloudera programming.I have the error "not starting RPC server as requested ,Use JMX(Storage service -> start rpc or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it" . I'm trying since hours to enable thift with nodetool but in vain.

I found a file "Enablethrift.html" in the Cassandra location but i didn't know what to do.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change in `cassandra.yaml` :

```
start_rpc: false
```

to

```
start_rpc: true
```